# What is a grid course?

Tags: instrument-flight-rules, navigation, polar

Reviewing the ILS 7 approach at Barrow ([PABR](http://www.airnav.com/depart?http://155.178.201.160/d-tpp/1603/05463ILD7.PDF)) revealed something I have never seen before:

[image]

Now, I saw the note (and diagram) in the upper left corner, so I was able to infer that this is a "**grid course**" but I still have no idea what this is.

Is there anyone on Aviation SE that knows and can explain?

Comment: This [website](http://www.theairlinepilots.com/forum/viewtopic.php?t=688) explains.